# NullPointer getting internationalization text at LocalizedTextUtil

Tags: java, internationalization, struts2

I have 3 language files idioma_CA.properties idioma_EN.properties idioma_ES.properties in the package "idiomas" and one default idioma.properties.

struts.properties has this properties:

hibernatePlugin.configurationType=annotation
struts.custom.i18n.resources = idiomas/idioma

So everytime I try to change the language struts2 ignores me and get always the text from the default properties at JSP's.
But using "getText" at execute method of my Action I get that NullPointerException whatever locale i have at request_locale.

Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

The localization letters after "idioma_" must be lowercase like "idioma_ca.properties"